# Replace value in request parameter

Tags: python, python-requests, tuples

I need to construct a web request to extract data from a JSON API.

This involves looping through a list of values in order to replace a request parameter.

So far, I located the request in the browser network tab, right clicked, copied as cURL(Windows). Then I pasted it into `https://curl.trillworks.com`, transformed to Python and pasted the result into Python.
Using this result via `requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)` works, but I don't want to insert values from my list by hand for every request.

However, I am unable to automate insertion of my list values into the `params` variable that is part of the request.

The `params` variable that `https://curl.trillworks.com` extracted looks like this

```
params = (
    ('A', 'B'),
    ('C', '{"type":"type_info","range":number}'), # "type_info" needs to be replaced for every request
    ('E', '{"F":{"G":1,"Hash":"value"}}'),
)
```

What is the easiest way to replace `type_info` by values from my list? The problem seems to be that `params` is an immutable tuple and when I do

`params_new = re.sub("type_info", list_value, params[1][1])`

I get

`'{"type":"list_value","range":number}'`

but I have no idea how to reconstruct `params` in full again so that I have:

```
params = (
    ('A', 'B'),
    ('C', '{"type":"list_value","range":number}'),
    ('E', '{"F":{"G":1,"Hash":"value"}}'),
)
```

I am open for alternative approaches as long as they're simple to understand.

Comment: Your values for `C` and `E` are literally just dictionaries, well `E` even got a nested one.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of tuple of tuples, use a dict for params. Then just update the value for respective key.

Comment: I didn't want to change the structure of `params` because I assumed this would break the request. Would it not?

Comment: As [per the docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/api/) you can pass `params` as _Dictionary, list of tuples or bytes to send
        in the query string for the :class:`Request`_. Chek also https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

Comment: What I meant was I feared the API/website wouldn't be able to deal with a different structure. But I guess your point was Python can take these different inputs and will still produce one and the same outgoing request?

Comment: Exactly. This is how you pass the params and `requests` will produce the proper `Request`. I guess you can always test if you don't believe.

Comment: It's just how this site presents the params (as tuple of tuples) when convert curl to requests

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you're stuck.  You simply repeat the structure, replacing the desired element:

```
params = (
    ('A', 'B'),
    ('C', params_new),
    ('E', '{"F":{"G":1,"Hash":"value"}}'),
)
```

If you need to generalize this, you can solve it by brute force with the specific structure:

```
params = (
    params[0],
    (params[1][0], params_new),
    params[2]),
)
```

If you need it even more general, then you'll need to write a comprehension that checks for the replacement key "type_info".  Use `params_new` when you find it; otherwise, use the corresponding element from `params`.  Does that get you moving?

Answer (score 0):

```
import copy

params = (
    ('A', 'B'),
    ('C', '{"type":"type_info","range":number}'),
    ('E', '{"F":{"G":1,"Hash":"value"}}'),
)

params_mutable = copy.deepcopy(params)
params_mutable = params_mutable[1][1] # this would return this '{"type":"list_value","range":number}'
```

**The deepcopy() function avoids these problems by:**

keeping a memo dictionary of objects already copied during the current copying pass; and

letting user-defined classes override the copying operation or the set of components copied.

for more info on it https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html here is the link for the docs